# How to set a home page in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [resume webapp from previous position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816286/resume-webapp-from-previous-position)

I want users to be shown the last page they visited when they come back. Example: user loads my app (I'm using PhoneGap), clicks on #second_page, closes the app, opens the app again. Instead of #home page, I want to show him #second_page right away.

I'm using localStorage to save the page:

```
$(document).on('pagechange', function() {
    localStorage.setItem('lastPage',window.location.hash);
});
```

I tried this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    var lastPage = localStorage.getItem('lastPage');
    if(lastPage) {
        $.mobile.changePage(lastPage);
    }
});
```

but I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trigger' of undefined" error in jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js:2.

Another idea is to do something along these lines:

```
var redirectedToLastPage = false;
$(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
    var lastPage = localStorage.getItem('lastPage');
    if(lastPage && !redirectedToLastPage) {
        $.mobile.changePage(lastPage);
        redirectedToLastPage = true;
    }
});
```

But it doesn't seem very elegant.  How should I do it?

Comment: See my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816286/resume-webapp-from-previous-position/12820115#12820115

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution:

```
$(document).on('pagechange', function() {
    var lastPage = '#'+$.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
    // console.log('setting last page to '+lastPage);
    localStorage.setItem('lastPage',lastPage);
});

var redirectedToLastPage = false;
$(document).bind("pagecreate", function(){
    var lastPage = localStorage.getItem('lastPage');
    if(lastPage // lastPage needs to be set
        && !redirectedToLastPage  // only do it on first pageload
        &&!window.location.hash // we don't want to redirect from pages other than the homepage
    ) {
        if($("div[data-role='page']"+lastPage).length) { // make sure a "page" div with that ID exists!
            // console.log('redirecting to '+lastPage);
            $.mobile.changePage(lastPage);
        } 
        // else {
        //  console.log(lastPage+' does not exist!');
        // }
    }
    redirectedToLastPage = true;
});
```

Please feel free to point out anything I might have done wrong :)